# Javascript function will not execute using Cookies

Tags: javascript, html, function, cookies

I made a javascript function and I am trying to execute it in the javascript area. However, it will not run. When I run the code it just does nothing. I am using Github, so if you want my full code, go to https://github.com/TheNumnut/Wars-of-Shares/blob/master/Login/index.html
I am trying to make a Login page for a game. I would rather use forms than prompts but I have not been able to do that. If somebody could tell me how to use forms I will greatly appreciate it.

This is my code:

```
function checkCookie(checkusername, checkpassword) {
  if (getCookie("username") != "") {
    setCookie("username", checkusername, 365);
    setCookie("password", checkpassword, 365);
  }
  else {
    if (checkusername != getCookie("username") {
      alert("Username wrong");
    }
    else {
      if (checkpassword != getCookie("password") {
        alert("Password wrong");
      }
     }
  }
  window.open("https://thenumnut.github.io/Wars-of-Shares/", "_self");
}
checkCookie(prompt("Username"), prompt("Password: ");
```

Please have a look at my other code in Github, because it also has not been working. Especially the profile page. None of the clickable text and links have been working. The link to the Profile Page is https://github.com/TheNumnut/Wars-of-Shares/blob/master/Profile/index.html

Comment: Do you realize that this "login" is just as strong as no login at all?

Comment: Your code is missing <html> opening tag. And as @Cerbrus said, user can login without any login.

Comment: This approach may be just as good at securing your site as no login at all, but nobody can steal your password if you didn't use one. Storing a password in a cookie makes it far easier for it to steal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS code has syntax errors.
You're missing an extra ) in the 7th, 11th and 42th line.

You can press F12 on your browser and check the console tab, where javascript errors are displayed.

However, I need to agree with the other users that this login method is not a good practice and it's very easy to bypass.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript source is available to the user of any website. Since the JavaScript runs in the user's browser, the code has to be transferred to the user's browser so the browser knows what to do. This means I as the user can view the source. In this case, by viewing the source I can see the line:

```
window.open("https://thenumnut.github.io/Wars-of-Shares/", "_self");
```

So I can bypass your log in page just by looking at the page source and going straight to `https://thenumnut.github.io/Wars-of-Shares/`